# AWS Relational Database Service - Can I view MySQL tables in the AWS management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I connected my RDS database with mysql workbench and created tables. Can I view these tables in AWS management console?

I tried query editor, but I am getting an message "query editor only supports Aurora Serverless databases".

Comment: In general, if AWS created the database technology (e.g. DynamoDB) then it will also provide AWS console access to the data. If AWS is simply providing a managed service on top of a third-party or open source database (e.g. MySQL) then AWS won't provide a client (because there's a wealth of clients already available).

Answer (score 2):

That's right, the query editor is available only for Aurora Serverless databases.

Amazon describes [Amazon Athena MySQL connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-mysql.html) that could help you achieve what you need.
But this may not be as quick solution as the query editor.

The other way would be using a MySQL client that can access the database (e.g. `mysql-client` from a Linux instance inside the VPC that the database resides).